# Can I use migration sql scripts names in flyway without description?

Tags: flyway

I use maven for db migration with flyway. And I want to use names of sql scripts like: "**test_1.1.sql**". But flyway throws exception: "*com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.FlywayException: Wrong migration name format*". If I use name: "**test_1.1__some_description.sql**", all goes fine.
But such format isn't acceptable for me. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not currently possible. It used to be an option in pre-2.0 versions. Removing it made it possible to detect a bunch of possible mistakes, which couldn't be reliably identified before.

On a all but the most trivial projects, having a description makes a lot of sense.

If you feel we overlooked a valid real world usecase for not having a description, please file an enhancement request in the issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks. One more question. Can I change path from "src/main/resources" to something different?

Answer (score 0):

There are some properties for modify flyway migration scripts naming convention.

**Properties Name:** `sqlMigrationPrefix` and `sqlMigrationPrefix`

In your Case `test` is  prefix for migration script and suffix is `.sql`.

So, Your properties should be set like:

`flyway.sqlMigrationPrefix = test
flyway.sqlMigrationPrefix = .sql`

At Last, Your naming convention should be **"test1_1__Some_Description"** where
`__` is use for separator for "`Migration Script Description`".